# Fancytree: get node at right click context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I have a right click context menu on fancytree and I would like to get a node object from within function call of 'disabled' property. So based on some data in node object, i would like to conditionally disable a menu item. But data object has only a random jquery selector and neither a node or node data object.

```
        contextMenu: {
              menu: {
                'Cut': { 'name': 'Cut', 'icon': 'cut' },
                'Paste': { 'name': 'Paste', 'icon': 'paste',
                    'disabled' : function(action,data) 
                    { 
                        logMessage("Node: "+ data.node.title + " " + data.node.tooltip);
                        if (data.node.data.isAllowed == true)
                            return false;
                        else
                            return true; 
                    }   
                },
                'sep1': '---------',
                'RefreshTree': { 'name': 'Refresh Tree', 'icon': 'refresh' },
                'sep2': '---------',
                'RefreshNode': { 'name': 'Refresh Node', 'icon': 'refresh' }
              },
              actions: function(node, action, options) {
                  logMessage("Action ["+action+"] "+JSON.stringify(node.data));
              .....
```

Answer (score 1):

OK. I got the answer.

```
              menu: {
                'Cut': { 'name': 'Cut', 'icon': 'cut' },
                'Paste': { 'name': 'Paste', 'icon': 'paste',
                    'disabled' : function(action,data) 
                    { 
                        var node = $.ui.fancytree.getNode(data.$trigger);
                        logMessage("Node: "+ node.title + " " + node.tooltip);
                        if (node.data.isAllowed == true)
                            return false;
                        else
                            return true; 
                    }   
                },
```